How about porting the usbhost code generated by stm32cube to gd32?
I have encountered a problem in my project, I need to port the usbhost code framework generated by stm32cubemx to gd32, without modification, it can detect the insertion of the u-disk, but there will be a problem when executing the write operation, I don't know if there is any porting success?(p.s. the chip model I used is gd32f107vc and then the corresponding stm32 model is stm32f107vc)
I looked at the manuals for both chips and found that most of their registers are pretty much the same, it's the small parts of them that differ, so I didn't want to use the official gd32 usb library to execute it, as it might involve other issues

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

In the usb_host.c change this void MX_USB_HOST_Init(void) to this code:


void MX_USB_HOST_Init(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USB_HOST_Init_PreTreatment */
 
  /* USER CODE END USB_HOST_Init_PreTreatment */
 
  /* Init host Library, add supported class and start the library. */
  if (USBH_Init(&hUsbHostFS, USBH_UserProcess, HOST_FS) != USBH_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (USBH_RegisterClass(&hUsbHostFS, USBH_MSC_CLASS) != USBH_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (USBH_Start(&hUsbHostFS) != USBH_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USB_HOST_Init_PostTreatment */
  (void)USBH_LL_ResetPort(&hUsbHostFS);
  USBH_Stop(&hUsbHostFS);
  if (USBH_Start(&hUsbHostFS) != USBH_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE END USB_HOST_Init_PostTreatment */
}



